# Assert a partial keyword of a value in arraylist in Protractor

Tags: javascript, arraylist, automation, jasmine, protractor

Is there any way we could do a assert of a partial word of a value from an arraylist using expect of Protractor ?

I have tried the below method which returns me a failure. Any suggestions or corrections to the below logic ?

```
var results=['Hello','Side Navigation','twice','jumbo'];
expect(results.indexOf('Navigation')!=-1).toBeTruthy(); 

Failures:
  Message:
[31m    Expected false to be truthy.[0m
  Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation
```

Comment: Iterating through results linearly and check if each item contains your item. is probably the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the items in the array using a plain old javascript function:

```
var arrayContainsText = function(array, text) {
    return array.some(function(item) {
        return new RegExp(text).test(item);
    });
});

var results=['Hello','Side Navigation','twice','jumbo'];
var text = 'Navigation';
expect(arrayContainsText(results, text)).toBeTruthy();
```